# Meu projeto não abre mais

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Meu projeto estava funcionando perfeitamente. Fui abri-lo agora e me dá esse erro:

[image: Erro]

Quando eu cheguei meu neto estava com meu notebook, mas não acho que ele (3 anos) danificaria. É mais certo ser vírus, mas scaneei e não peguei nada no meu computador. Como eu conserto isso e abro a *solution* e os meus projetos que estão nela?

Comment: Vai no arquivo de solution e abre como um bloco de notas copia e cola aqui para podermos entender o problema.

Comment: Você consegue abrir o arquivo `.csproj` que faz parte da *solution*?

Comment: Se o problema é só a *solution* é criar uma nova e importar os *projects* e as classes que estão no directório

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Usando controle de versão***

Se você estiver usando algum versionador de código você pode tentar desmapear seu projeto atual e mapeá-lo novamente. (Faça isso somente se você não tem nenhuma alteração pendente)

***Sem controle de Versão***

Se o problema for apenas na solução do seu projeto você pode tentar adicionar as classes do seu antigo projeto em um projeto novo.

1. Criar novo projeto

Do mesmo tipo do projeto antigo

2. Adicionar os arquivos (classes, referências, imagens e etc) no novo projeto

Para no *Solution Explorer* isso *clique com o botão direito* do mouse em cima do projeto novo e depois em *'Add existing item'*;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Ache e selecione* os arquivos do projeto antigo e clique em *Add*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os arquivos deverão ser adicionados na nova solução e você deve ser capaz de continuar seu trabalho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Beleza, achei que desse para corrigir. Pelo que vejo, terei que criar outro. O meu projeto é grande, isso que eu estava tentando não fazer, mas pelo que vejo, não tenho escolha. É criar um novo e passar meio dia migrando, kkkkkk