# Projeto class library não abre. Dá erro no .csproj dele

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Esse é o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há como gerar um novo .csproj ou consertar esse ou tenho que criar um novo projeto e importar tudo pra dentro dele?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É provável que o arquivo esteja corrompido. Infelizmente a melhor solução é criar outro projeto do zero e incluir os arquivos.

Pelo ficheiro do projeto original você pode ver quais arquivos vai precisar - não apenas de código em C#, mas também arquivos de recursos e outros formatos, caso existam. O mais complicado é obter as referências - tente abrir o arquivo .csproj corrompido em um editor de texto e descobrir quais referências ele usa, para que possa reconstruí-las.

Comment: Não abre, fica aquele monte de "quadradinho".

Comment: Descobri que eu já havia postado e como tem resposta não posso remover o post. É uma pergunta duplicada. Eu dupliquei. Favor, fazer o que deve ser feito em casos assim. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65300/meu-projeto-n%C3%A3o-abre-mais